JavaMailSender threw exception when building project using SMTP preferences from external file
I created a @Bean MailConfig to have the user configure SMTP preferences rather than statically placing them in the project's application.properties file.
The problem is that although all the configuration is loaded correctly and emails are sent when I start the project, but I get an error during the build:
Stack trace:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'javaMailSender' defined in class path resource [com/IOTProjectUI/config/MailConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'javaMailSender' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SMTP preferences are not set correctly.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 100 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'javaMailSender' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SMTP preferences are not set correctly.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SMTP preferences are not set correctly.
    at com.IOTProjectUI.config.MailConfig.javaMailSender(MailConfig.java:44)
    at com.IOTProjectUI.config.MailConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d71899e.CGLIB$javaMailSender$0(<generated>)
    at com.IOTProjectUI.config.MailConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d71899e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$22288389.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.IOTProjectUI.config.MailConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8d71899e.javaMailSender(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 114 more


This is the MailConfig:
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        CiPreferences.readPreferences();

        String host = CiPreferences.properties.get("smtpHost");
        String portStr = CiPreferences.properties.get("smtpPort");
        String username = CiPreferences.properties.get("smtpUsername");
        String password = CiPreferences.properties.get("smtpPassword");
        String auth = CiPreferences.properties.get("smtpAuth");
        String starttls = CiPreferences.properties.get("smtpStarTtls");

        if (host == null || portStr == null || username == null || password == null || auth == null || starttls == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SMTP preferences are not set correctly.");
        }

        int port;
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt(portStr);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SMTP port: " + portStr, e);
        }

        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);
        mailSender.setUsername(username);
        mailSender.setPassword(password);

        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", Boolean.parseBoolean(auth));
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", Boolean.parseBoolean(starttls));
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        return mailSender;
    }


As I said, when I run emails are sent. This is the config file:
smtpHost=stest@test.com
smtpPort=25
smtpUsername=test@test.com
smtpPassword=
smtpAuth=false
smtpStarTtls=true
smtpSender=test@test.com


What is CiPreferences? It looks as though it might well return smtpPassword as null rather than an empty string, but I don't know what it is so I can't say. Also it does sound like something other than this instance of JavaMailSender is sending your emails.

It is not JavaMailSender that throws this exception. It is your own code, and it is probably because smtpPassword is not set in your config file.

Hello all. CiPreferences is a custom class. As I said, the exception is thrown only when I build the project. That's why the problem could not be related to a bad configuration of the prefences (E.g. smtpPassword). I've fixed it changing the way how the profile "install" try to have access to that file.
